# Javascript will not throw a new Error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dojo

I have some code that just has me baffled. I have searched online, and I cannot find anything like this, though I'm not thinking I'm the first =) I'm using dojo, and I don't have any idea if that has anything to do with the problem I'm having. The problem is that Firebug will not throw an error I would like it to throw. However, when debugging it in Safari, the error is thrown??? I do this sort of thing all the time, and for some reason it will not work here.

Here is the code sample:

```
var formSubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var f = testForm.domNode,
        map = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < f.elements.length; i++){
        var elem = f.elements[i];
        map[elem.id] = elem.value;
    }


    if (!map.id && !map.field1) {
        ***// -- this error will not be thrown --***
        throw new Error("you must supply some data"); 
    }
}



testForm = new Form({
    encType: "multipart/form-data",
    method: "post",
    onSubmit: formSubmit
}, "testForm");
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this would not work in Firebug?

Comment: If it's not thrown then it's [more than likely] not reached.

Comment: Is the `formSubmit` function executing at all?

Comment: @Ryan If it's a conforming JavaScript engine (I guess it could be *shadowed* to another value by silly code, but..)

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your input. I appreciate it more than you know. The code is executing within the if statement. I can put an console.log statement in there, and it will be output in firebug, but the error won't be displayed. Also, the exact same code in Safari's debugging tools will display the error...that's what's most confusing to me.

Answer (score 8):

The error probably is thrown, but the function that throws the error is being called from an event handler so the error ends up in the system event handling code where it's either caught there (not caught in your code) or it simply gets ignored.

When you say, "it's not thrown", what were you expecting to see?  Did you have a `try/catch` somewhere that you were expecting to catch the exception?  Throwing an exception doesn't have any generic UI of it's own.  It throws the exception and then it's up to some higher level code to catch the exception and do something with it.  If there is no higher level code in that event loop to catch the exception, then it just aborts the execution of that event handler.

Comment: I see what you're saying. One LARGE piece of information I left out is that the code is being stopped. It's just not displaying the error in firebug. I think what you're saying must be happening, but still don't get why the error is displayed in Safari? So how would I get this type of error to display in firebug? It's working in other parts of my code, and when I used jQuery, I never ran into this problem (not to say I don't like using dojo, because I really like this framework). If I used a try/catch, would that be a better way to consistently display the error?

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be?  Do you want to display an error message to the user?  throw is NOT for displaying errors to the user.  If so, don't use `throw`, use `alert`.  Each browser can be configured for what to do with uncaught exceptions - it's an end-user setting, not something you should use or rely on in your code.  If you throw an exception and desire anything other than just stopping execution of that JS thread of execution, you should be catching it somewhere else.  If you want to show the user a message, don't use `throw`.  Use something like `alert(msg)`.

Comment: Thanks, your comment made me recheck if my promises had a `catch()` written for it. Turns out it didn't! Now my errors are logging properly :)